# proof of Box–Muller transform (polar form)

Tags: calculus, probability, derivatives, normal-distribution, sampling

There're proofs of [Box–Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) available online but my book (pattern recognition and machine learning) seems to have put it in a different form.

[image]

[image]

I didn't follow **the derivation of equation 11.12**, can anyone please help? Thanks!

**EDIT**
As mentioned in Nadiels's answer, there's a mistake in formula 11.10 and 11.11, as logarithm has to take in a positive number (PRML [errata](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-errata-1st-20110921.pdf)).

Comment: What book is this? How is $p(z_1,z_2)$ defined?

Comment: @nbubis hi the book is "pattern recognition and machine learning", p(z1,z2) is "a uniform distribution inside the unit circle with p(z1,z2)=1/pi", thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first thing there is an error in equations $(11.10)$ and $(11.11)$ and in fact you should have the transformations
$$
y_i = z_i \left( \frac{-2 \ln r^2 }{r^2 } \right)^{1/2}
$$
and in particular we have
\begin{align*}
\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \left(y_1^2 + y_2^2 \right) \right) &=\exp\left( \left( z_1^2 +z_2^2\right)\frac{\ln(r^2)}{r^2} \right) = r^2,
\end{align*}
which using the inverse function theorem tells us that if 
$$
\mathbf{J} =\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial z_1} & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial z_2} \\
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial z_1} & \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial z_2}\end{bmatrix},
$$
then to get the desired result we want to show that $\left| \operatorname{det}(\mathbf{J}) \right| = 2/r^2$. Or
$$
\left| \left(\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial z_1}\right)\left(\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial z_2}\right) - \left(\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial z_2}\right)^2 \right|= \frac{2}{r^2}.
$$
Let
$$
y_i = z_i h(r^2), \qquad \mbox{where } h(r^2) = \left(-\frac{2\ln r^2}{r^2} \right)^{1/2}
$$
then
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial z_1}\right)\left(\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial z_2}\right) - \left(\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial z_2}\right)^2 &= h(r^2)^2+2r^2h'(r^2)h(r^2) \\
&=h(r^2)^2 + \frac{2}{r^2}\left( \ln(r^2) - 1 \right)\\
&=\frac{-2\ln(r^2)}{r^2} + \frac{2 \ln r^2}{r^2} - \frac{2}{r^2} \\
&= -\frac{2}{r^2}.
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: I guess the bonus question is whether it should be geometrically obvious that the determinant is proportional to the inverse of the radius?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I took me some time to fully understood it, the result just looks so supersizing, do you know the intuition behind this method? or are there any similar transforms to this?

Comment: Definitely better to take the time to fully understand an answer than accepting too early! I went looking and it turns out this correction is in the [errata](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-errata-1st-20110921.pdf) for the first printing of PRML. As for motivating the result you could try the Wikipedia and then check the articles they cite, that is why I was curious as to whether the inverse square law property of the determinant added anything heuristically, but I don't know that it does

Comment: right, thank you much :)

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, a pdf in one set of variables is given by the pdf in another set of variables multiplied by the determinant of the Jacobian matrix.

In you case, you must calculate:
$$\left|\left(\begin{array}(\partial z_1 / \partial y_1 & \partial z_2 / \partial y_1  \\ \partial z_1 / \partial y_2 & \partial z_2 / \partial y_2\end{array}\right)\right|$$
Now, this looks a bit complicated, since you are given $y_1,y_2$ in terms of $z_1,z_2$ and not the other way round. Luckily, we can use the Inverse function theorem to get that:
$$\left|\frac{\partial (z_1, z_2)}{\partial (y_1, y_2)}\right|= \left|\frac{\partial (y_1, y_2)}{\partial (z_1, z_2)}^{-1}\right|=\left|\frac{\partial (y_1, y_2)}{\partial (z_1, z_2)}\right|^{-1}$$

So you should be able to calculate the derivatives and then the inverse determinant.